# dynamic array of objects in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, dynamic

I have created this two codes classes.

```
classdef master < matlab.mixin.Copyable


  properties
      id
      list
   end
   methods
        function this=master(id)             
            if nargin > 0
                this.id = id;
                this.list = repmat(msg,1,20);
            end
        end 
   end
end

classdef msg < matlab.mixin.Copyable


 properties
      id
      dest
      ttl
   end
   methods
        function this=msg(id,dest,ttl)             
            if nargin > 0
                this.id = id;
                this.dest = dest;
                this.ttl = ttl;
            end
        end 
   end
end
```

In another part of my code I try to delete one or more objetc "msg" from array "master.list" using the following:

```
   function verifyMsgToDiscard(this,t)
        i = 1;
        while (i <= numel(this.list))
            m = this.list(i);
            if (t > m.ttl)
               this.list = this.list(this.list~=m); %remove m of the list
               clear m; %delete m from the system
            end 
            i= i + 1;
        end
    end
```

I am getting the error:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in master/verifyMsgToDiscard (line 117)
                m = this.list(i);

The problem I think is why I am iterating over the master.list in the same time I modify the number of elements on it. In addition I can add and remove new objects "msg" in the "list" then its size varies. How I can do this in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're trying to remove msg objects having `ttl` to be smaller than `t`. This is the Matlab way of removing elements:

```
this.list = this.list(t <= [this.list.ttl]);
```

Note that `t <= [this.list.ttl]` generates a logical index.